# Have Śaivācāryas defeated Vaiṣṇavācāryas in debates?

Tags: history, vaishnavism, shaivism

If such things happened state those incidents with proper inscriptional data!!

Answer (score 0):

```
   INVITATION TO AACHAARYAs
```

Debates never occurred between Aacharyaas. Aacharyaas of a cult dont involve in debates rather deliver PRAVACHANAMs on GOD dedicated in their aatman.

Debates occured between courteers of Kings and Aacharyaas only because Kings could not reframe their worship rules to masses based on all people recommendations. They wanted to hear the truth from Aacharyaas by testing them(In KaliYuga) rather than gifting & surrendering portion of assets to them.

```
 GLOBAL RULE of SAINT DIVINITY
```

(referenced in ARTHASHAASTRA(decoded version of VEDAS on Saint treatise by KAUTILYA though Kautilya changed to Chaanakya after lots of hate crimes by King soldiers) : An aachaarya (of any sect including Jains/Pastors(in Abrahamic cults also) must not be invited to a place without gifting them some assets to respect their Divinity.

```
    SHAIVA - VAISHNAVA
```

Shaivism is a sect but Siddha yogis from the sect lived natural ascetic life without scriptures. Scriptures would be handled by courteers only.

Vaishnavism is a bhakthi sect where lot of hymns and songs were promoted.

Aacharyaas just guided the followers in 4 stages of VARNAASHRAMA DHARMA. Aacharyaas followed ascetic & austere life with special powers acquired from GOD (one cannot test the powers to understand truth rather follow their PRAVACHANAMs and practice whatever applicable because a human can never be an expert in all norms of life & status).

```
      HARMLESS CRITICISM
```

Proof: Swami Desikan wrote SHATADOOSHANI as a critic on other sects trying to deny the concept of AATMAA and idol worship, but he never degraded any aethists during his time. A few black pantheons tribes who were not obedient in other sects tried to test Supernatural powers of his Holiness using tamed reptiles - Snakes, Lizards and Crocodiles. These involve NO ORDERS/COMMITMENTS FROM ANY AACHARYAAS OF A SECT.

CONCLUSION of good gesture

DEMONAIC traits of unlearnt or undeveloped humans tried to Supercede AACHARYAAs Divine traits but all AACHARYAAs succeeded due to their Devotion & dedication towards AHIMSA & SANAATANA DHARMA.